# Сomplex number equation: $z^3+\frac{(\sqrt2+\sqrt2i)^7}{i^{11}(-6+2\sqrt3i)^{13}}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

please tell me how I can solve the following equation.

$$z^3+\frac{(\sqrt2+\sqrt2i)^7}{i^{11}(-6+2\sqrt3i)^{13}}=0$$

What formula should I use? If possible, tell me how to solve this equation or write where I can find a formula for solving such an equation. I searched for it on the Internet, but could not find anything useful.

Comment: I think you think that this is more difficult than it really is. Can you solve an equation like $z^3+2i=0$? Because this one isn't much different from that. And if you _can't_ solve my simpler equation, then start there instead of with yours.

Comment: Write it in a polar form.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt2+\sqrt2i=2e^{\frac{\pi i}4}$.

And $-6+2\sqrt3i=4\sqrt3e^{\frac{\pi i}6}$.

And $i^{11}=-i$.

So we have $z^3-\frac{2^7e^{\frac{7\pi i}4}}{i\cdot (4\sqrt3)^{13}e^{\frac{13\pi i}6}}=0\implies z^3+\frac{i}{e^{\frac{5\pi i}{12}}2^{19}3^{\frac{13}2}}=0\implies z=-\frac1{576\cdot 2^{\frac13}\cdot 3^{\frac16}}e^{\frac{\pi i}{36}},-\frac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{36}}}{{576\cdot2^{\frac13}\cdot 3^\frac16}}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}$ or $-\frac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{36}}}{{576\cdot2^{\frac13}\cdot 3^\frac16}}\cdot e^{\frac{4\pi i}3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify at first, $$(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}i)^7=64\sqrt{2}(1-i)$$
to prove this write $$\sqrt{2}^7(1+i)^7$$ Calculate $$(1+i)^3\cdot (1+i)^3\cdot (1+i)$$

Comment: I think the simplification requires a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You have to use the exponential form of complex numbers: set $Z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}$ and observe that, for instance,
$$\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i=\sqrt 2(1+i)=\sqrt 2\cdot \sqrt2\mathrm e^{i\tfrac\pi 4}=2\,\mathrm e^{i\tfrac\pi 4}, \;\text{&c.}$$
so that $\;(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i)^7=2^7 \mathrm e^{i\tfrac{7\pi}4}$.

Can you proceed similarly for the denominator?

Comment: I will try, just this topic is new for me, I just started to study it today)

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that $\sqrt2+\sqrt2i=2\left(\frac{\sqrt2}2+i\frac{\sqrt2}2\right)$ and $-6+2\sqrt3i=4\sqrt3\left(-\frac{\sqrt3}2+i\frac12\right)$ should help you to express the given complex numbers in the polar form. You can then use [de Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to simplify the expression. From there you might be able to continue further.